# new Thread created when calling SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Is a new Thread created when Runnable is used with `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`?

Comment: sometimes good to know at threads botton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502671/what-does-this-statement-mean

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No,a new thread is not created when Runnable is used with `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()`.
The Event Thread will end up calling the run() method of the Runnable when it's turn comes up on
the event queue.

Comment: If the AppContext's AWT EDT is not currently running, then a new AWT EDT will be created.

Answer (score 6):

invokeAndWait [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed synchronously on the AWT event dispatching thread

Comment: da do run run run da do run run

Comment: @ Jason S what do you mean "a do run run run da do run run "!!

Answer (score 3):

No. The purpose of the method is to run the Runnable on the GUI event thread, which I would assume you have already.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no. The current thread blocks until the EventQueue runs the Runnable.

Answer (score 0):

> Causes doRun.run() to be executed
>   synchronously on the AWT event
>   dispatching thread.

no it triggers an event on the AWT event thread (which is already running in gui apps)